# ModuleNotFoundError after installing from github

Tags: numpy, installation, pip, osmnx

I installed the OSMNX package from GitHub with pip using
`pip install git+git://github.com/gboeing/osmnx.git`
and I confirmed OSMNX was installed as it showed up on `pip list`.

However, when trying to `import osmnx` I receive an error that NumPy cannot be found. I definitely have NumPy installed, and I confirmed that NumPy shows up in `pip list`, so I'm not sure why OSMNX can't find NumPy. Any ideas on how to make OSMNX recognize NumPy?

Here's the full error
[image: ModuleNotFoundError numpy]

Comment: Which version of NumPy do you have installed? Edit: and which version of Python is that?

Comment: @Ivan numpy 1.19.4 & python 3.9.1

Comment: Are you running on a notebook?

Comment: @Ivan yes, I am

Comment: You should try restarting your kernel, it might work.

Comment: @Ivan Unfortunately it still doesn't work after restarting

Comment: I'm affraid I can't help without taking a look at your code/setup. It's a weird issue. I tried downloading and importing `osmnx` just now, and it worked fine.

Comment: @Ivan hmm ok. I'll try starting with a fresh conda environment, that might do the trick.